# How to remove HTML in email output generated by Power Automate for lookup columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, email, flow, power-automate

My Power Automate solution produces the desired values except I can't figure out how to remove the HTML metadata in the email output. Instead of:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.FieldLookupValue"},"LookupId":958,"LookupValue":"Toyota Camry"}
```

I just need the value (Toyota Camry). Please see the attachment for an illustration. I also tried the HTML-to-text feature and it produced the same email output.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

[image: Power Automate solution showing current and desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below expression in "Check previous status" action:

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['d']['Car']['LookupValue']
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you